# Indicator function, derivative of a differentiable function?

Tags: derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Given any set $E\subseteq [0,1]$, does there exists any differentiable function $g$ such that $g'(x)=\mathbb{1}_{E}(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]?$ ($\mathbb{1}_{E}$ is the indicator function of $E$)

I do not know how to answer this in general but this is what I did.

If $E$ is not Lebesgue measurable, then such function does not exist. Indeed, we know that $\mathbb{1}_E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable function if and only if $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set. Now, since $g'(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{g(x+1/n)-g(x)}{1/n}$ is measurable, as a limit of a sequence of measurable functions, we cannot have $g'(x)=\mathbb{1}_E(x)$ since $\mathbb{1}_E$ is not measurable.

Is what I did a good approach to this problem? For an arbitrary set $E\subseteq [0,1]$, is it possible to prove that such a function does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property. See [Darboux's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

Comment: So, we can say that such a function does not exist? Is this right? Suppose by contradiction that $g$ exists. Take $x\in E$ and $y\in [0,1]\backslash E$ such that $x<y$. Then, $g'(y)=0<1/2<g'(x)=1$. Therefore, there exists $z\in (x,y)$ such that $g'(z)=1/2$ which is impossible since $f$ takes only values $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @Cachoro can you see this, if this works?

Comment: Yes, this is it. Your function $g'$ only exists when $1_E$ is constant, meaning that $E=\emptyset$ or $E= [0,1]$.